# create List inside twirl template

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, twirl

Usually I create all the stuff like that:

```
@(courses: List[models.Course])
```

Then I pass the List from the controller into the view from the render() method.

but this is some kind of special case, It's actually a partial and I would have to add the list of courses into every method in the controllers.

**logic:**

main.scala.html is the main file which calls all the other views via a **@content** variable.

There is a twitter bootstrap navbar which get's called into every view, I don't want to pass the List from every controller action into the view but instead I'd like to call it like so:

**pseudo code:**

```
@List[Course] = { Course.find.all()) { courses => 
    @for(c <- courses) {
        @c.getCategory()
     }
}
```

notes: This is pseudo code I have no idea about Scala.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was that:

```
 @defining( CourseCategory.find.all()) { courses =>
       @for(i <- courses) {
          <li><a href="#">@i.getCategoryName</a></li>
        }
  }
```

I'm not sure if this is a good approach but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can as well short it to just:

```
@for(i <- CourseCategory.find.all()) {
    <li><a href="#">@i.getCategoryName</a></li>
}
```